# How to generate dynamic HtmlTableCells in ASP.NET properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < difference; i++)
          {
              HtmlTableRow row=new HtmlTableRow();
              row.Align = "center";

for (int k = 0; k < sessionVars.differentlists+1; k++)
              {
                  HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell("cell"+k+i);
                  row.Cells.Add(cell);

              }
                  Table3.Rows.Add(row);

                  [...]
```

That I think should generate as with a number of cells equal to that of sessionVars.differentlists+1, and in certain way it does, but it looks like it creates them outside of what would be the table.

This code that I think should be equivalent for the case in which sessionVars.differenlist+1=3 works fine:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < difference; i++)
          {
              HtmlTableRow row=new HtmlTableRow();
              row.Align = "center";


                  HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
                  HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
                  HtmlTableCell cell3 = new HtmlTableCell();
                  row.Cells.Add(cell);
                  row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                  row.Cells.Add(cell3);

                  Table3.Rows.Add(row);

                  [...]
```

Any idea on how to achieve an equivalent of the second code for any possible value of differntlists?

Comment: at a high level what are you trying to do? You can databind a DataGrid to any datasource, and all columns and rows will be dynamically generated.

Comment: Your first code looks just about right... i think your iteration counters are a bit wrong, it seems you should start i at 0 not at 1 and sessionVars.differentlists+1 should be just sessionVars.differentlists without the +1... take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4